CM docker container unhealthy due to heathz/ready failing with 500 error
When running docker compose up -d, the cm container shows as unhealthy.
There is no error in the log except for

2024-07-12 20:01:23 ::1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - ::1
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.5933 - 500 19 13 1

when I exec into the cm container and do a invoke request I get the same error
All other containers including the CD, Solr and the mssql are running fine and have no error

A notable discrepancy is that my CM container pings /healthz/ready,
whereas the CD containers ping /healthz/live. Further investigation
revealed that a Healthcheck.ps1 script determines the URL to ping
based on the LOCALAPPDATA path and the presence of a Healthcheck folder at that location. This folder is missing in my CM container.
(when I checked with other team members their CM containers ping the
/healthz/live url and they have the Healthcheck folder)

What I have tried so far:
I verified all other containers are up and running and that there is no error in Solr, mssql or CD containers
Approach I
I did this several times to see if this fixes the issue, but I still get the same error
docker-compose down; docker system prune -f; docker system prune -a C:\projects\sitecore-xp-enterprise\docker\clean.ps1 Docker-compose build --no-cache solution docker-compose build --no-cache cm; docker-compose build --no-cache docker-compose up -d;
Approach II
Stop CM container
Delete all files and folders from ~\docker\build\cm path.
Restart CM container.
Approach III
exec into the CM container and validated the web.config file
did iisreset
also tried to hit the curl http://127.0.0.1/healthz/live endpoint but still the same error
Update:
So what I did was I followed the instructions in this article and disable the CM Health check to see if it gives me some info
https://konabos.com/blog/disabling-traefik-healthchecks-in-sitecore-docker
And when I did that I was able to get the Traefik container started.
With that I can see that my CD comes up Health and also loads the Sitecore Welcome page
But the CM still has the same error



hey renuka run the clean/stop .ps file and then run start.ps .  Sometimes containers does not stop correctly so this can happen .

Check web.config file in docker. And check if URL Rewrite Module is installed on CM

@MarekMusielak yes the web.config  has those updates. What is interesting to note is that other team members in my team who also setup their new laptop did not run into this issue. Its just my setup that has this issue

Is your Sitecore version 10.2 ? If yes, do check below blog. Sitecore keeps on releasing new images and if you do not specify exact version, there is a possibility of compatibility mismatch. https://blogs.perficient.com/2023/11/15/troubleshooting-sitecore-image-update-issue/

Updated the ticket with the latest updates

The health check is attempting to access /healthz/ready and receiving a 500 status code. This indicates that our application is experiencing a YSOD, but we are unable to view it in the Sitecore logs (because Sitecore cannot even start).
To view the raw output, run the following command in the shell:
curl http://127.0.0.1/healthz/ready All container types can benefit from a similar strategy. Each container may have a slightly different health check, but this method gets to the bottom of the issue.
We must ensure that Docker is executing in Windows containers if the docker error container is unhealthy error appears.
To test this, right-click on the Docker icon in the system tray and see if the ‘Switch to Linux containers’ option appears. If so, Docker for Windows containers is already running.

We have to ensure that the option ‘Use Docker Compose V2’ is unchecked.

Run the following commands and see if that works:

docker-compose stop
docker-compose down
iisreset /stop
docker-compose up -d




Did all those steps but I am running into the same error.
Doing the curl http://127.0.0.1/healthz/ready
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
gives the same error

A 500 error might be caused by configuration issues or DLLs deployed to the CM.
Below are the steps to resolve the issue:

Stop your CM container if running.
Delete all files and folders from ~\docker\deploy\platform path.
Restart CM container.


Did you mean docker\deploy not docker\build?

I meant ~\docker\deploy. I will update above answer. Thanks.

The Deploy folder does not have a CM folder. Moreover even the folders for Sps and website and xconnect at that path are all empty with just the .gitkeep

Updated the ticket with the latest updates

There can be a number of reasons for healthcheck failing. The best way to find out the exact cause would be to go inside the cm container and do an Invoke-WebRequest to the localhost URL as follows:

run this command: docker exec -it "cmID" powershell.exe (Replace cmID with first 4 characters of the cm container id
The above command should take you inside the cm container with C:\inetpub\wwwroot as the current root directory in PS
run this command: Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost -UseBasicParsing. This will show you the exact error.

Apart from these, you could also check the following:

Try removing the cm image and let it be recreated. It can be time-consuming but you could also remove all the images or build the images with --no-cache so that you are certain that the images are correct.
You could remove the custom website files, databases and solr indexes so that you can confirm that the default Sitecore instance loads.
You can also try changing the Sitecore minor version that is more stable. You can check out all the Sitecore images here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.md


Already did that I have posted the error I get
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

If you have VS Code with Docker extensions, you can inspect and view the web.config files for possible issues.

I did validate the web.config and it has no errors. I also replaced the web.config file from a working instance of CM container but still the same error

can you share some more details? logs from cm? and as mentioned above try to start the default blank docker sitecore instance and check if that works.

Updated the ticket with the latest updates
